# Get Information of relation table using pivot table data

Tags: php, laravel-5, pivot, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4. I have 2 tables `destination` and `user` and a pivot table `destination_user`.

destination table

```
---|------
id | name
---|------
1  | sth
```

user table

```
---|------
id | name
---|------
1  | sth
```

and finally Pivot table

```
--------------|--------
destination_id| user_id
--------------|--------
1             | 1
2             | 1
3             | 2
```

I created a model for pivot table named `destinationUser`.

My `destination` model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\models;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\DestinationUser;
use App\Models\DestinationImage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Destination extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'destinations';

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    } 

    public function destinationUser() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\DestinationUser');
    }
}
```

I want to get all the destinations with their respective user detail using pivot table. I have tried so far is this:

```
$destinations = $this->destination->with('user', 'destinationUser')
                        ->whereHas('destinationUser',  function($query) { 
                            $query->where('user_id', user()->id);})
                        ->paginate(20);
```

`dd($destinations[0]->destinationUser);` gives me `destination id` and `user id` but I want user detail. How can I achieve this. Thank You for your help

Comment: you need a many to many relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @madalinivascu can you be more specific please

Comment: what's the table name for the pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

You need a many to many relationship:

```
class Destination extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'destinations';


    public function destinationUser() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

controller

```
$destinations = $this->destination->with('destinationUser',  function($query) { 
                            $query->where('user.id', user()->id);})
                        ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: `destinationUser()` is a relation for pivot table., I have defined a relation of `destination` table with `user` table using this:           `public function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    }`

Comment: you can name it however you want

Comment: What I need was a many to many, but i defined one to many relationship. Got it

Comment: `belongsToMany` will internally join  the destinations user and pivot tables, so you don't need a hasMany pivot table relationship, read the documentation in the link i provided

Comment: I think many to many relationship is not good. Because, a user can have many destinations but a destination has only on user(one who create it). So, this relationship doesn't actually works as expected.

Comment: @vijayrana then why do you have a pivot table?

Comment: you add the user_id to the destinations table and then do a one to many relationship

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161679/discussion-between-vijayrana-and-madalinivascu).

Answer (score 0):

As I was searching for faster execution of queries, there was a wrong design of tables. There is more load and time of execution for 3 table with pivot rather than 2 tables without pivot. So, I figured it out and corrected.